# Multiple markers in a loback log statement

Tags: slf4j, logback, markers

Scenario:

- Our log file is monitored by Tivoli.
- I am planning to mark statements which need to picked up by Tivoli. So I have markers say 'TIVOLI_P1' 'TIVOLI_P2' etc, P1, P2 being error priority
- Additionally I want to classify errors for which Tivoli will not raise alerts if those have happened for say 10 times, till the issue is fixed. For such errors which need de duplication, I have a seperate marker say DEDUP.

Problem: I can't find support for logging with multiple markers. As in the Logger.log() doesn't take an array of markers. What would be ideal would be to have a statement say with 2 markers like:

TIVOLI_P1 DEDUP

I could combine them into a single marker, but they really mean convey different things and are seperate.

I am sure there would be good reason, but why doesn't logback/slf4j take an array of markers?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

For SLF4J, following approach can be useful:

```
 Marker dupMarker = MarkerFactory.getDetachedMarker("TIVOLI_P1");
 dupMarker.add(MarkerFactory.getMarker("DEDUP"));

 LOGGER.error(dupMarker, "A log message");
```

If you check *org.slf4j.MarkerFactory*, there are 2 static methods which returns *Marker* object as: *getMarker(String name)* and *getDetachedMarker(String name)*.

Acording to *org.slf4j.helpers.BasicMarkerFactory* implementation, main difference is *getMarker* uses a caching strategy while *getDetachedMarker* always returns new instance.

On base line you need such detached marker approach, otherwise once you add "DEDUP" marker to your "TIVOLI_P1" marker, they will always hang out together, unless you detach "DEDUP" matcher via *detachMarker* method. However this won't be a good approach if you are in multi-threaded environment.

If you are concerned with the creation cost of this 2 step operation, you can introduce a cache which holds such complex marker instances.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create a root marker that does nothing and use [`Marker.add`](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Marker.html#add%28org.slf4j.Marker%29) to include the list of actual markers as children.

*Note:* I am new to SLF4J so this might not be the intended / "correct" way to use markers.